# cvtColor "code" for 16-bit grayscale images

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tiff

I have unsigned 16-bit grayscale tiff images as numpy arrays. I want to do some image processing on these images using OpenCV. I am converting the `numpy` array to `Mat` format using `cv2.cvtColor(src, code)`. As far as the documentation goes, I am having a hard time finding the right **code** argument to correctly convert 16-bit grayscale images without losing any information.

Previously, I read the images directly using `cv2.imread(src, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`. However, I don't have the original image files now, only the pickled numpy array. I am looking for the code in cvtColor which does a similar thing as `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tough to follow. All you appear to have are some files containing pickled Numpy arrays, correct?

If so, you don't need any `imread()`, you just need to unpickle the files and you will have Numpy arrays of the type that **OpenCV** uses to hold images. Check their `dtype` is `np.uint16` and their shape appears correct.

Comment: I was getting errors due to the fact that my `base_image` did not match the shape of the rest of the images. The problem is solved now!